# Complex analysis and entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Be $f : \mathbb{C} \Rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a entire function. Supose that is exist $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ such as $$ a Re(f(z)) + b Im(f(z)) \leq c$$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $f$ is constant.

I want prove that $f$ is bounded and apply the Liouville's Theorem, but i don't know show that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Note your inequation says $f$ doesn't take its values in some half-plane. Find $c$ such that $\frac{1}{f(z)-c}$ is entire and bounded.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}} \newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$We must assume at least one of $a$ and $b$ must be nonzero otherwise the inequality says nothing about $f(z)$.

Recall the $\exp(\cdot)$ is increasing so:
\begin{align}
e^{a\Re f(z)+b\Im f(z)} \leq e^c
\end{align}
Now note that $$|e^{af(z)-bif(z)}|=e^{a\Re f(z)+b\Im f(z)}\leq e^c$$ Furthermore $\exp({af(z)-bif(z)})$ is entire as well and bounded, hence by Liouville $\exp({af(z)-bif(z)})=K$ for some $K\in\mathbb{C}$. Now differentiating yields:
$$ f'(z) (a-ib) \exp({af(z)-bif(z)})= 0$$
We know $\exp(\cdot)$ is nonzero so $f'(z)(a-ib)$ must be zero so $f'(z)=0$.
And we get that $f(z)$ is constant.